# Why there is no "Match Error" in following code?

Tags: elixir

I am new to Elixir, learning from official website.

Why is output equal to {2,1}?

```
iex> x = 1
iex> {x, ^x} = {2, 1}
{2, 1}
```

Doesn't it give match error as x is matched to 2 in that 2nd equation and ^x = 1 should be not allowed?

I tried searching online but didn't find satisfying answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is *expression*. Expressions work in the following way: they grab the context, are evaluated, and then return the result.

In this case, the expression is `{x, ^x} = {2, 1}`. [`Kernel.SpecialForms.=/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#=/2) is a macro, that receives the left and the right sides and then returns a result of the expression.

In this context, `x` was set to one, and **this value would be used everywhere in this expression**. The actual rebinding of `x` to `2` in the outer context (your `IEx` session) would happen *after* the expression is evaluated and returned.

Comment: Thank you!!  ```The actual rebinding of `x` to `2` in the outer context would happend after the expression is evaluated and returned.```  I thought otherwise. Now the pin operator makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

This is explained fully in the [The pin operator](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/pattern-matching.html#the-pin-operator) documentation.

Quoting the relevant sentence first:

> pattern match against a variable's ***existing value rather than rebinding the variable***

```elixir
iex> {x, ^x} = {2, 1}
```

Can be re-written as:

```elixir
iex> {x, 1} = {2, 1}
```

---

> ### The pin operator
>
> Variables in Elixir can be rebound:
>
> ```elixir
> iex> x = 1
> 1
> iex> x = 2
> 2
> ```
>
> However, there are times when we don't want variables to be rebound.
>
> Use the pin operator `^` when you want to pattern match against a variable's *existing value* rather than rebinding the variable.
>
> ```elixir
> iex> x = 1
> 1
> iex> ^x = 2
> ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: 2
> ```
>
> Because we have pinned `x` when it was bound to the value of `1`, it is equivalent to the following:
>
> ```elixir
> iex> 1 = 2
> ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: 2
> ```
>
> Notice that we even see the exact same error message.
>
> We can use the pin operator inside other pattern matches, such as tuples or lists:
>
> ```elixir
> iex> x = 1
> 1
> iex> [^x, 2, 3] = [1, 2, 3]
> [1, 2, 3]
> iex> {y, ^x} = {2, 1}
> {2, 1}
> iex> y
> 2
> iex> {y, ^x} = {2, 2}
> ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {2, 2}
> ```
>
> Because `x` was bound to the value of `1` when it was pinned, this last example could have been written as:
>
> ```elixir
> iex> {y, 1} = {2, 2}
> ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {2, 2}
> ```